# Redirect all users hitting top level site

Tags: javascript, redirect, web, sharepoint

I have a site hierarchy in SP looking like this:

```
http://acme.com

    http://acme.com/hr

    http://acme.com/it
```

Under each page there are lists and libraries, etc. like this:

```
http://acme.com/lists/xList

http://acme.com/lists/yList

    http://acme.com/hr/lists/hrList1

    http://acme.com/hr/lists/hrList2

    http://acme.com/it/lists/itList1

    http://acme.com/it/lists/itList2
```

What I need is a javascript type redirect (not that great with JS) that will take anyone hitting http://acme.com should redirect the users to http://newAcme.com including every list and asset belonging to the acme page should forward list this:

```
http://acme.com -> http://newAcme.com
http://acme.com/lists/xList -> http://newAcme.com/lists/xList
http://acme.com/lists/yList -> http://newAcme.com/lists/yList

http://acme.com/hr -> no redirect
http://acme.com/hr/lists/hrList1 -> no redirect
http://acme.com/hr/lists/hrList2 -> no redirect
http://acme.com/it -> no redirect
http://acme.com/it/lists/itList1 -> no redirect
http://acme.com/it/lists/itList2 -> no redirect
```

To reiterate... anything belonging to the top level site should be redirected to the new top level site, any subsites under the old site should not redirect the user anywhere.

All I have so far is a script in the master page is:

```
<script type="text/javascript>
    window.location = "http://newAcme.com";
</script>
```

But all this does is redirect everyone on every page including the subsites (which I do not want a redirect on) on the old domain because the master page contains this code.  My thoughts are just including the script on the actual top level page and not include it in the master page.  Does anyone have any suggestions for this?  I think I've clearly laid out what I am after.  I appreciate any support.

Comment: You need to solve it within your server configs. Nginx or apache configuration allows such things. For example [Nginx http proxy](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html)

Comment: this is hosted within IIS... does that make a difference?

Comment: I don't know IIS, sorry, but google can help you. I just show you a one of the possible ways

Answer (score 0):

Have U tried sth like

```js
window.location = window.location.replace(/oldAddress/ig, "newAddress");
```

just pay attention that if you have a page with a name containing the "oldAddress" it will be replaced with "newAddress"

Comment: Won't your above example redirect any site with "oldAddress" in it?  Including the subsites that I do not want redirection on?   Any thoughts around this?

Comment: well what do redirect-needed pages have in common in their path?